# Symfony2: FOS_Userbundle Duplicate definition when updating db schema?

Tags: symfony

I am trying to use the FOS_UserBundle for managing my users but everytime I try to update the db

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

I get following error:

**Duplicate definition of column 'username' on entity in a field or discriminator column mapping. fos user bundle**

It also happens with 'email' when I comment out username.

My user class is actually very basic:

```
namespace My\MyBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{

/**
* @ORM\Id
* @ORM\Column(type="integer")
* @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
*/
protected $id;

/**
* @ORM\Column(type="string", length="100") 
*/
protected $username;

/**
* @ORM\Column(type="string", length="100") 
*/
protected $name;

/**
* @ORM\Column(type="string", length="100")
*/
protected $firstname;

/**
* @ORM\Column(type="string", length="150")
*/
protected $email;

}
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your `My\MyBundle\Entity\User` extends `FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User`, which in turn extends `FOS\UserBundle\Model\User`, which already has a `$username` field. It also has an `$email` field. So you simply need to remove the `$username` and `$email` fields from your class.

Comment: Great thanks igorw! .. some things just seem to not pointed out deeply enough for beginners.. Thanks!

Comment: But if you need to add you own assertions to those fields with your own validation groups how could you do it if you don't have the properties in your own user class anymore?

Comment: I'm getting this error even i delete the email or username fields. I know this question is old...

Comment: @R.CanserYanbakan I have fixed my problem by deleting the extra attributes (duplicated one by FOSUserBundle like:username, email...) from this file UserBundle\Resources\config\doctrine\User.orm.yml

Comment: @flu right! I'm having this problem right now trying to make the username and email loggable with the StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle...

Comment: @GottliebNotschnabel Have a look at jzpl's answer below. If you extend the Model instead of the Entity you should be able to add you own annotations like ``loggable``.

Comment: I already used the Model. It doesn't throw an error in my problem, it seems to be StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle or FOSUserBundle specific.

Answer (score 10):

Extend with FOS\UserBundle\Model\User, not FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User class. You should always extend with Model, not Entity.

Comment: Because the entity already "contains" annotations. By extending the model you can do your own annotations on the field already existing

Comment: In this case beware taht you need to redefine all the annotations (no one will be inherited from `FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User`)

Answer (score 7):

For me, it worked by *removing* the Column annotation.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column  --> remove this line!
 */
protected $password;
```

You can use **@ORM\AttributeOverrides** to User or BaseUser class to override annotations from BaseUser.
Example:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 * @AttributeOverrides({
 *      @AttributeOverride(name="password",
 *          column=@Column(
 *              nullable = false,
 *              unique   = true,
 *              length   = 123
 *          )
 *      )
 * })
 class User extends BaseUser
 {
 ...
```